# How to fix issue with socket.io-client connecting to server?

Tags: node.js, socket.io

All of a sudden my socket.io-client won't connect to my socket.io server. everything was working correctly, then it stopped connecting to the server. I'm developing locally.

I've checked my server & client setup, made sure my IP address was correct (`ifconfig`), and I've considered that port 3000 may be blocked by firewall. but I've been using it successfully up till now so I don't know why it would be blocked all of a sudden.

server.js:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const server = require("http").createServer(app);
const io = require("socket.io").listen(server);
const port = process.env.PORT || 3000;
io.on("connection", socket => {console.log("a user connected...socket ID: "+socket.id})
server.listen(port, () => {console.log("server running on port: "+port})
```

client:

```
import React from "react";
import {
  View,
  Text,
  StyleSheet,
  AsyncStorage,
  TouchableOpacity,
  FlatList
} from "react-native";
import { USERNAME } from "../config";
import io from "socket.io-client";
const socket = io("###.##.##.###:3000");

export default class Lobby extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      username: "",
      queue: []
    };
  }
...
```

when I start the server, the console correctly logs `server running on port: 3000`
but when I try to connect the client by navigating to a screen in react-native client, the console no longer logs `a user connect...socket ID: ########` as it once did.

Comment: Have you been updating any dependencies, namely React Native, since the last time it worked?

Comment: negative on updates

Comment: Try running a socket.io-client in the web browser, make sure to use the same connection string. If the web client can't connect the problem is in the server, otherwise it's in the mobile app.

Comment: hypothetically, if updates were made, what would be a course of action to take?

Comment: it was because my connection didn't have "http://" before the ip. added it, fixed.